# How to get style NSWindow title bar like this

Tags: macos, cocoa

I've seen this title bar style with a lot of Mac apps and I like the aesthetics (taller, larger title, custom buttons). How can I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The taller titlebar and aligned buttons are changed by setting the titleVisibility property:

`window.titleVisibility = NSWindowTitleHidden; // Obj-C`

`window.titleVisibility = .Hidden // Swift`

The title is most likely a custom view (possibly just an NSTextField) in the title bar or toolbar, with the font size cranked up.